# How to efficiently use a Postgres DB with Python

Tags: python, postgis, geojson, geodjango

I have a Postgres DB with a lot of lines that are too long and so now I want to split those lines into smaller ones.

This is why I started writing a little python script for that job. Basically it fetches my lines like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ogc_fid, id, ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry) as geometry, ST_Length(wkb_geometry) as length, height FROM cont OFFSET " + str(offset) + " LIMIT " + str(limit) )
```

Here's my first problem. In order to further work with the data I have to select the geometry as JSON. I'll come to that later.

Now I iterate over the lines and make something like this:

```
sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (ogc_fid, id, wkb_geometry, height) VALUES(" + ogc_fid + ", " + row_id + ", ST_Line_Substring(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'" + geometry + "\'), " + str(rangeFrom) + ", " + str(min(rangeFrom + stepWidth, 1)) + "), " + str(height) + ");"
cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
```

So if I didn't use `ST_AsGeoJSON` in the select, I couldn't append it to my command cause it can only append a string.

That way my whole script is very slow. It always has to convert my geometries into JSON and then back from JSON.

Is there a datatype that python can handle?

Is there a more efficient way of dealing with geometry fields?

I heard of GeoDjango. Could that help here?

Comment: Why not do it in a single query?

Comment: What Jakub said. Do it directly in Postgres. It isn't at all clear why you would want all the overhead of JSON for this. If you must do it in Python, use a library that deals with geometries directly, such as shapely of fiona.

Comment: Well... I tried doing it as a Postgres function, but as it would then all be one big transaction, it fails as there are too many queries. Basically what I need to do is to figure out if a line is too long and if so, I need to cut it into pieces. I know that the JSON part is slowing everything down like crazy... that's why I'd like to get rid of it... I'll have a look at `shapely`

Comment: There is no way of doing it directly as a postgres function but forcing it not to do everything in one transaction but to write the data after some loops, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [`geoalchemy2`](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/). Personally I would look at using the [Object Relational Mapper (ORM)](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/orm_tutorial.html) model for working with your data, for example:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# Enter your database connection below
engine = create_engine('postgresql://gis:gis@localhost/gis', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

Base = declarative_base()

class Cont(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cont"
    ogc_fid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(Integer)
    wkb_geometry = Column(Geometry("LINESTRING"))
    height = Column(Float)
    # Other database columns here
```

From there you can setup a session and easily query the database:

```python
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

And write a query to get back the lines you want to update:

```python
query = session.query(Cont).filter(Cont.geom.ST_Length() > tolerance)
```

Queries are iterators, so it's easy to loop over them and work with the data, especially as [geoalchemy2](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/shape.html) has inbuilt [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) integration.

```python
from geoalchemy2.shape import from_shape, to_shape

new_rows = []

for row in query:
    shapely_geometry = to_shape(row.wkb_geometry)
    # ... some operations to create `new_geom`
    new_rows.append(
        Cont(
            ogc_fid=row.ogc_fid,
            id=row.id,
            wkb_geometry=new_geom.wkt, #shapely geometries have a wkt property
            height=row.height
        )
    )
```

Then you can commit all your rows at once:

```python
session.add_all(new_rows)
session.commit()
```

Or commit by chunk by splitting your new rows into chunks ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671301/379566)):

```
for chunk in (new_rows[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, len(new_rows), chunksize)):
    session.add_all(chunk)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: you are super awesome!!!! thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: One more question... So, once I have a row, I'd like to figure out it's length. `shapely_geometry.ST_Length()` didn't did the trick for me. And once I have it I'd need to run `ST_Line_Substring` to split the line. Sorry to bother you, but my python skills are very limited... would be so super awesome if you might tell me how to do those two commands!!!

Comment: I managed to figure it out! What took 2 weeks before took 6hours now :) thanks again!!!!